# How can you use a trait's associated type for const generics and the length of arrays?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a situation that would ideally be structured as following:

```rust
pub struct ConstraintProperties<const COUNT: usize> {
    particles: [ParticleReference; COUNT],
}

pub trait Constraint {
    fn project(&self, particle_source: &mut [Particle], dt: f64, static_pass: bool);
}

pub trait ConstraintData {
    const COUNT: usize;
    fn properties(&self) -> ConstraintProperties<{ Self::COUNT }>;
    fn constraint(&self, particles: [&Particle; { Self::COUNT }]) -> f64;
    fn gradients(&self, particles: [&Particle; { Self::COUNT }]) -> [Vec3; { Self::COUNT }];
}

impl<C: ConstraintData> Constraint for C {
    fn project(&self, particle_source: &mut [Particle], dt: f64, static_pass: bool) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, I am running into the following error: "type parameters may not be used in const expressions."

How can I get around this so that I can use the associated constant of the trait to govern the const generic and the lengths of arrays that the trait's functions take?

Comment: I believe this is currently a limitation of the compiler. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/60551

Answer (score 0):

On nightly, you can use [`#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560):

```rust
#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]

pub trait ConstraintData {
    const COUNT: usize;
    fn properties(&self) -> ConstraintProperties<{ Self::COUNT }>;
    fn constraint(&self, particles: [&Particle; Self::COUNT]) -> f64;
    fn gradients(&self, particles: [&Particle; Self::COUNT]) -> [Vec3; Self::COUNT];
}
```

But note that this feature is highly experimental and not recommended in production.